# Fragment Overlapping Toolbar ViewPager

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am using Florent's Material ViewPager [library](https://github.com/florent37/MaterialViewPager), where each and every Tab hosts independent Fragment and few of them contains recyclerview.

Now the concern is my Fragment overlapping header / material viewpager, as shown in below screenshot:

[image]

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @BindView(R.id.materialViewPager)
    MaterialViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setTitle("");
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        final Toolbar toolbar = mViewPager.getToolbar();
        if (toolbar != null) {
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        }

        mViewPager.getViewPager().setAdapter(new FragmentStatePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()) {

            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                switch (position % 4) {

                    case 0:
                        return MenuFragment.newInstance();

                    case 1:
                        return MenuFragment.newInstance();

                    case 2:
                        return MenuFragment.newInstance();

                    default:
                        return MenuFragment.newInstance();

                }
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return 4;
            }

            @Override
            public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
                switch (position % 4) {
                    case 0:
                        return "Selection";
                    case 1:
                        return "Actualités";
                    case 2:
                        return "Professionnel";
                    case 3:
                        return "Divertissement";
                }
                return "";
            }
        });

        mViewPager.setMaterialViewPagerListener(new MaterialViewPager.Listener() {
            @Override
            public HeaderDesign getHeaderDesign(int page) {
                switch (page) {
                    case 0:
                        return HeaderDesign.fromColorResAndUrl(
                            R.color.green,
                            "http://phandroid.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/android_google_moutain_google_now_1920x1080_wallpaper_Wallpaper-HD_2560x1600_www.paperhi.com_-640x400.jpg");
                    case 1:
                        return HeaderDesign.fromColorResAndUrl(
                            R.color.blue,
                            "http://www.hdiphonewallpapers.us/phone-wallpapers/540x960-1/540x960-mobile-wallpapers-hd-2218x5ox3.jpg");
                    case 2:
                        return HeaderDesign.fromColorResAndUrl(
                            R.color.cyan,
                            "http://www.droid-life.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/lollipop-wallpapers10.jpg");
                    case 3:
                        return HeaderDesign.fromColorResAndUrl(
                            R.color.red,
                            "http://www.tothemobile.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/original.jpg");
                }

                //execute others actions if needed (ex : modify your header logo)

                return null;
            }
        });

        mViewPager.getViewPager().setOffscreenPageLimit(mViewPager.getViewPager().getAdapter().getCount());
        mViewPager.getPagerTitleStrip().setViewPager(mViewPager.getViewPager());

        final View logo = findViewById(R.id.logo_white);
        if (logo != null) {
            logo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mViewPager.notifyHeaderChanged();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Yes, the title is clickable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.github.florent37.materialviewpager.MaterialViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/materialViewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:viewpager_logo="@layout/header_logo"
        app:viewpager_pagerTitleStrip="@layout/material_view_pager_pagertitlestrip_newstand"
        app:viewpager_logoMarginTop="100dp"
        app:viewpager_color="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:viewpager_headerHeight="200dp"
        app:viewpager_headerAlpha="1.0"
        app:viewpager_imageHeaderDarkLayerAlpha="0.2"
        app:viewpager_hideLogoWithFade="false"
        app:viewpager_hideToolbarAndTitle="true"
        app:viewpager_enableToolbarElevation="true"
        app:viewpager_parallaxHeaderFactor="1.5"
        app:viewpager_headerAdditionalHeight="20dp"
        app:viewpager_displayToolbarWhenSwipe="true"
        app:viewpager_transparentToolbar="false"
        app:viewpager_animatedHeaderImage="true"
        />
```

**MenuFragment.java**

```
public class MenuFragment extends Fragment {

    ....

    public static MenuFragment newInstance() {
        return new MenuFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        ...

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

        ....
    }

}
```

**fragment_one.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: In your xml of viewPager you have set hideToolbar and title true, this might me hiding toolbar. Also check in onCreate if  toolbar is null by debugging

Answer (score 0):

Add attribute `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` to your `LinearLayout` to make relative scrolling with `MaterialViewPager`.

Hope this will work.